# Trying to import a class written in typescript to javascript NodeJs showing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am creating a node express application.
For my use case, I have a 1.ts file with a class as:

```
export class blah {
    constructor(props) {

    }
    tt() {
      console.log('logging function');
    }
}
```

in my  2.js file i am importing as

```
const blah = require('./1')
var b = new blah.blah()
console.log(b.tt())
```

But  nothing in console.function is not being called.

How do i fix this problem.
tsconfig.json file content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
 "exclude": [
"node_modules"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Did you recompile with `tsc 1.ts`?

Comment: yes here is my package.json scripts
"build-ts": "tsc && nodemon ./src/index.js",
"dev": "nodemon -e ts  --exec \"yarn build-ts\""

and i am running by yarn dev

Comment: Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: here it is.. updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

It must be 
const blah = require("./1")

Comment: You are using {} it's used for destruction of object..means when your library export multiple things and want to access part of it then you can use destruction syntax..

Comment: no its not working with your solution, its giving the same result.

Comment: updated the question, its recognising the class but not able to call the function.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer *why* you think it should look like that, and why the OP's code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting as an answer to post the contents of the files. This code works for me. I am running just the command `tsc` in the directory with the files. Output files are `1.js` and `1.js.map`. Then I run `node 2`. The output is

```
logging function
undefined
```

(On a sidenote: It prints `undefined` because the call `console.log(b.tt())` tries to print the return value of `b.tt()`, but it does not return anything)

`const blah = [...]` gives me the same error you got.

Directory structure (everything on the same level):

- 1.ts
- 2.js
- tsconfig.json

1.ts

```
export class blah {
    constructor(props) {

    }
    tt() {
      console.log('logging function');
    }
}
```

2.js

```
const {blah} = require('./1')
var b = new blah()
console.log(b.tt())
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: even if i add a return statement in the function its not printing anything in the console.

Comment: Did you try just copying the contents of the files I posted and following the steps to rule out a problem with the typescript compilation? Based on if it's working or not you could rule out some possibilities for error. Maybe there is a problem with `nodemon -e ts --exec \"yarn build-ts\`